# GCP: Debian stuck at setting up dbus

Tags: debian, software-installation, gnome3, d-bus, google-cloud

I have been trying to install GUI, i.e. gnome and lxde, into Debian 9 stretch in google cloud computing instance. I have even increased the cpu, ram, harddisk size. However, the installation is always stuck at "Setting up dbus (1.10.26-0+deb9u1)"

My last attempt is letting it sit for 6 hours now. It's still stuck there.

What can I do?

Thanks and Regards

Edit1: I found this line. Does this have to do with this error?

```
Setting up rtkit (0.11-4+b1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants/rtkit-daemon.service → /lib/systemd/system/rtkit-daemon.service.
Job for rtkit-daemon.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status rtkit-daemon.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
rtkit-daemon.service couldn't start.
```

Edit2: I shutdown the instance and get thefollowing. Not sure if this may mean anything or not related at all - again because I forced shutdown the system.

```
Setting up dbus (1.10.26-0+deb9u1) ...
Job for dbus.service canceled.
invoke-rc.d: initscript dbus, action "start" failed.
● dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-05-02 21:38:17 UTC; 31min ago
     Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
 Main PID: 15748 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
May 02 21:37:52 instance-2 systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
May 02 21:37:52 instance-2 dbus-daemon[15748]: Failed to start message bus: Could not get UID and GID for username "messagebus"
May 02 21:38:17 instance-2 systemd[1]: dbus.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 02 21:38:17 instance-2 systemd[1]: dbus.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 02 21:38:17 instance-2 systemd[1]: dbus.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package dbus (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Comment: got the same problem, fresh clean debian installation followed by lxde install, hangs at the same line with the same previous error about rtkit. installed within virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to complete the installation by first installing the `dbus` library alone, and just after proceeded with the `lxde` installation:

```
sudo apt-get install dbus
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

Answer (score 0):

Restart your server and then do

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

happen to me always when i setup vnc it stuck and then have to restart vps